# Split plot model - How to perform on R

Tags: r

I want perform a split plot model on R like I run using `SAS`.

```
 PROC GLM DATA=A; BY EXP;
       CLASS REPETICAO FATOR1 FATOR2;
       MODEL &VAR1 = REPETICAO FATOR1 REPETICAO*FATOR1 FATOR2 FATOR1*FATOR2;
       TEST  H=FATOR1 E=REPETICAO*FATOR1;
```

How I can run this model using `R aov function`?

I tried some like this:

```
aov( resp ~ REPETICAO+FATOR1*FATOR2+Error(REPETICAO*FATOR1), data=y)
```

I need that R generate the correct F test for "`FATOR1`"

Somebody can help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some minutes to read our [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So you tried `aov`. What happened? Please provide a short example data set for `y`. Your can [edit] your question to include it. Using `aov_result <- aov(...)` and then `summary(aov_result)` prints out information about the ANOVA result.

Comment: Also see [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16532098/3082472) to see how to give others on SO easy acces to some data to play with and explore your problem.